# Update each group's property with the lowest element's property of the corresponding group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like

Old table

```
acc|name|group|priority
1  |aa  |g1   |1
2  |ff  |g1   |2
3  |ss  |g1   |2
4  |gg  |g2   |3
5  |uu  |g2   |4
6  |dd  |g2   |4
.  |.   |.    |.
xx |xx  |xx   |x
```

I want to update name to new table with sql to

New table

```
acc|name|group|priority
1  |aa  |g1   |1
2  |aa  |g1   |2
3  |aa  |g1   |2
4  |gg  |g2   |3
5  |gg  |g2   |4
6  |gg  |g2   |4
.  |.   |.    |.
xx |xx  |xx   |x
```

In table, name in group g1 must update to aa  with minimum priority in group g1.
Do you have any idea to update all group with name in minimum priority?

Comment: Add all informations as text or inline Image, not as link

Comment: Sorry, I see no differences between your old and new table images. Please [edit] your question to show your tables as text. If you indent each line of text four spaces, they will be displayed as tables.

Comment: I just edited my question. Please see it again. Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to update the name of each group with the corresponding name of each group having the minimum priority, right?

Comment: Yes. Anyone who can help will be gladly appreciated. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you would try the solution on your own effort first.

Initially I am sharing the idea:

1. First you need to know the name of entry of each group which holds
   the minimum priority. In order to know the minimum row for each
   group just google it. This [**article**](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) might be useful.
2. Then you need to make an `inner join` between your main table and the
   table you've just got from **step 1** on matching groups and then update
   each row with the name of the row which holds priority greater than the minimum priority
   of the corresponding group.

Finally come up with a solution of your own and check with the solution I am giving right below:

```
UPDATE your_table YT 
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
A.*
FROM your_table A 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    `group` AS group_name,
    min(priority) AS min_priority
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY `group`
) AS B 
ON A.`group` = B.group_name
AND A.priority = B.min_priority
) AS helper 
ON YT.`group` = helper.`group`
SET YT.name = helper.name 
WHERE YT.priority > helper.priority;
```

---

[**See Demo**](http://rextester.com/AWWT55248)

---

**Test schema:**

```
create table your_table (
    acc int, 
    name varchar(30), 
    `group` varchar(30), 
    priority int
);


insert into your_table values(1,'aa','g1',1);
insert into your_table values(2,'ff','g1',2);
insert into your_table values(3,'ss','g1',2);
insert into your_table values(4,'gg','g2',3);
insert into your_table values(5,'uu','g2',4);
insert into your_table values(6,'dd','g2',4);
```

**Caution:** `group` is a reserved word in mysql. Whenever you name your identifier by any of the reserved words you need to use backtick (`) [**...Read more**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)